# Can you list all folders in an S3 bucket?

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto

I have a bucket containing a number of folders each folders contains a number of images. Is it possible to list all the folders without iterating through all keys (folders and images) in the bucket. I'm using Python and boto.

Comment: I think this is answered pretty well here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3337912/quick-way-to-list-all-files-in-amazon-s3-bucket

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [list()](http://boto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ref/s3.html#boto.s3.bucket.Bucket.list) with an empty prefix (first parameter) and a folder delimiter (second parameter) to achieve what you're asking for:

```
s3conn = boto.connect_s3(access_key, secret_key, security_token=token)
bucket = s3conn.get_bucket(bucket_name)
folders = bucket.list('', '/')
for folder in folders:
    print folder.name
```

**Remark:**
In S3 there is no such thing as "folders". All you have is buckets and objects.

The objects represent files. When you name a file: `name-of-folder/name-of-file` it will look as if it's a  file: `name-of-file` that resides inside folder: `name-of-folder` - but in reality there's no such thing as the "folder".

You can also use AWS CLI (Command Line Interface): 
the command `s3ls <bucket-name>` will list only the "folders" in the first-level of the bucket.

Comment: How to do it in boto3?

Answer (score -2):

Yes ! You can list by using prefix and delimiters of a key. Have a look at the following documentation. 

    **http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ListingKeysHierarchy.html**