# How to access a file on Amazon S3 from the Command Line?

Tags: amazon-web-services, macos, amazon-s3, terminal, homebrew

## Question:

Is there a simple way to access a data file stored on Amazon S3 directly from the command line?

### Motivation:

I'm loosely following an [online tutorial](https://blog.kissmetrics.com/improve-by-predicting-churn/) where the author links to the following URL:

```
s3://bml-data/churn-bigml-80.csv
```

It is a simple csv file, but I can't open it using my web browser, or with `curl`. The tutorial opens it with BigML, but I want to download the data for myself. Some googling tells me that there are a number of python and Scala libraries designed for S3 access ... but it would be really nice to open or download the file more directly.

I use Mac and am a big fan of homebrew, so the perfect solution (for me) would work on this system.

#### Bonus Question:

Is there any good way to see the contents of an Amazon E3 bucket (that I *don't* own)?

The nature of the file (80% of a particular data-set) makes me suspect that there may be a `churn-bigml-20.csv` file hiding somewhere out there. My automatic approach would be to try and curl / open the expected file ... the solution to the first question will allow me to check this hunch but in an ugly way. If anyone knows of a way to remotely explore the contents of a specific S3 bucket, then that would be very useful. Again, exploring google and SO tells me that there [are libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3337912/quick-way-to-list-all-files-in-amazon-s3-bucket) for this, but a more direct approach would be useful.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The **[AWS Command Line Interface](https://aws.amazon.com/cli/)** (CLI) is a unified tool to manage AWS services, including accessing data stored in Amazon S3.

The AWS Command Line Interface is available for Windows, **Mac** and Linux.

If the bucket owner has granted public permissions for `ListBucket`, then you can list the contents of the bucket, eg:

```
aws s3 ls s3://bml-data
```

If the bucket owner has granted public permissions for `GetObject`, then you can copy an object:

```
aws s3 cp s3://bml-data/churn-bigml-80.csv churn-bigml-80.csv
```

Both of these commands works successfully for me.

See also:

- [AWS Command Line Interface Documentation](https://aws.amazon.com/documentation/cli/)

Comment: This is great! And aws is also installable using brew: `brew install awscli`

Comment: any reason why this is happening?

curl https://ryft-public-sample-data.s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/DNS/dns1.log -s -o dns1.log  works 

but *not* 

aws s3 cp s3://ryft-public-sample-data/DNS/dns1.log .
fatal error: An error occurred (403) when calling the HeadObject operation: Forbidden

Comment: @shrek The `aws s3 cp s3://ryft-public-sample-data/DNS/dns1.log .` command works fine on my computer. It downloaded the file.

Answer (score 4):

There's a neat tool called `s3cmd` that will do this.

- It works on Mac (with the homebrew package manager)
- It lets you download from Amazon S3 to your local machine
- It lets you browse Amazon S3 buckets (even when you don't own them)

### Installation and Setup

```
brew install s3cmd
```

Configuring the s3cmd requires that you have an amazon s3 account. This is free, but you need to sign up for it [here](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/).

```
s3cmd --configure
```

Configuration involves specifying your access / secret key pair, and a few other details (I used defaults for everything). If you want to use HTTPS then you can install `gpg` with brew, and set a few more configuration options at this point. Be warned - the gpg_passphrase that you use is stored in a local plain-text configuration file!

### Use:

Now for the exciting bit: downloading my file to desktop!

```
s3cmd get s3://bml-data/churn-bigml-80.csv ~/Desktop
```

Listing the contents of the remote bucket:

```
s3cmd ls s3://bml-data/
```

### Additional Functionality:

This is beyond the scope of the question but seems worth mentioning: s3cmd can do other things like `put` data into the bucket (and make it public with the -P flag), delete files, and show the manual for more information:

```
s3cmd -P put ~/Desktop/my-file.png  s3://mybucket/
s3cmd del s3://mybucket/my-file-to-delete.png
man s3cmd
```

### Credit:

Thanks to [Neil Gee](http://www.coolestguidesontheplanet.com/downtown/connect-amazon-s3-bucket-command-line-os-x) for his tutorial on s3cmd.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to download the file in linux terminal, you have to make the file as public.

FYI: Everyone will have access to one or all of the following: read this object, read and write permissions.

Once this has been done. Right click on the file >> Download as >> then you may able to see a popup.

Right-click the download link and choose " Copy link location. >> then paste it on a notepad. Then select the link before question mark for example.

> https://s3-ap-nrtheast-1.amazonws.com/backup/pan.hosting/2017-01-15/earth.tar.gz?response-content-disposition=attachment&X-Amz-Security-Token=%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FwTEigAJ4GvimzYt3gQegUHaRSe%2BnLWeND%

Then enter the command below on your command terminal.

> ## wget  https://s3-ap-nrtheast-1.amazonws.com/backup/pan.hosting/2017-01-15/earth.tar.gz