How I can compare two AWS S3-Buckets, to generate some comparison report
I am having AWS S3 buckets with version enabled.
For each object

Object Key

VersionId , Last Modified , size



Is there any Service available to achieve this report whether data from S3 buckets having match in context with above mentioned criteria ?
It is possible to write a java utility, but interested into looking for AWS way of running some service which can give data on this.
AWS Lambda cant be use here since its short termed service and iterating over each and every key w.r.t. versions took considerable time period.
Currently I am having a Java based utility ready with me which can do iterative data collection and eventually do compare, but that's still manually doing fetching operation.
If something AWS come up with such comparison then it will be value added.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45513538/how-to-get-the-file-diff-between-two-s3-buckets  sth like this?

There is no AWS-provided service that does this, but there are various options you could try. How many objects (including versions) are in the bucket?

Total count is 800k (including version ids)

@JohnRotenstein wouldn't even possible with S3 Batch Operations ?

As mentioned, there is no such service.  You'll probably want to setup a S3 Inventory report, or a metadata index and compare the results of that.

Given that you have 800,000 object versions in each bucket, making API would be quite slow because each ListBucket API call returns a maximum of 1000 objects.
I would recommend activating Amazon S3 Inventory, which can provide a daily or weekly CSV file listing all objects. If you activate this on both buckets, you could then compare the two CSV files to identify differences between the buckets.
You might be able to perform the comparison using a Diff utility, or worst-case you could write some code to identify the objects that are different between the buckets.
